# SBT 1.5.5 giving error while running test with -mem option

Tags: sbt, upgrade, circleci

While upgrading from sbt 1.2.8 to sbt 1.5.5, we faced issues in running test.
We are running the tests in circleci pipeline. With 1.2.8, `-mem 4096` option was working fine. However with 1.5.5, the command was failing with **killed** message, and exit code 137(out of memory). However after removing option `-mem 4096` the build is working successfully. Also, one more behaviour noticed was if the image used was having 1.2.8 sbt installed and build.sbt contains 1.5.5 sbt version, then also the tests were passing. Can someone suggest what could be the possible explanation for this behaviour.?